# Jboss EAP 7.1 ServiceModuleLoader returning null

Tags: jboss, jmx, jboss-eap-7

I'm using Jboss EAP 7.1 and when i try to dumpAllModuleInformation from ServiceModuleLoader, i'm getting null pointer exception, however i could see results for LocalModuleLoader. Attaching the Stack Trace below.

Basically i'm trying to see all loaded resources for my war file. I'm really not sure what's the reason for null pointer exception. All other operations like dumpModuleInformation, getDependencies, getModuleDescription, getModulesPathInfo, refreshResourceLoaders, relink and unLoadModule throwing IllegalArguementException: Module specification is null. Only queryLoadedModuleNames is returning my war filenames. Application is running fine without any issues. Jconsole is also throwing the same exception. I need to find a way to see all loaded jars for my war file. Standalone server is hosted with multiple war files, so planning to write a JMX program to get loaded dependencies for all of my wars/ears. Can you guys help me on this

```
javax.management.RuntimeMBeanException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.rethrow(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:839)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.rethrowMaybeMBeanException(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:852)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:821)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.jboss.as.jmx.PluggableMBeanServerImpl$TcclMBeanServer.invoke(PluggableMBeanServerImpl.java:1503)
    at org.jboss.as.jmx.PluggableMBeanServerImpl.invoke(PluggableMBeanServerImpl.java:724)
    at org.jboss.as.jmx.BlockingNotificationMBeanServer.invoke(BlockingNotificationMBeanServer.java:168)
    at org.jboss.remotingjmx.protocol.v2.ServerProxy$InvokeHandler.handle(ServerProxy.java:950)
    at org.jboss.remotingjmx.protocol.v2.ServerCommon$MessageReciever$1$1.run(ServerCommon.java:153)
    at org.jboss.as.jmx.ServerInterceptorFactory$Interceptor$1.run(ServerInterceptorFactory.java:75)
    at org.jboss.as.jmx.ServerInterceptorFactory$Interceptor$1.run(ServerInterceptorFactory.java:70)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AccessAuditContext.doAs(AccessAuditContext.java:92)
    at org.jboss.as.jmx.ServerInterceptorFactory$Interceptor.handleEvent(ServerInterceptorFactory.java:70)
    at org.jboss.remotingjmx.protocol.v2.ServerCommon$MessageReciever$1.run(ServerCommon.java:149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader$MXBeanImpl.doGetResourceLoaders(ModuleLoader.java:857)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader$MXBeanImpl.getModuleDescription(ModuleLoader.java:866)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader$MXBeanImpl.doDumpModuleInformation(ModuleLoader.java:737)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader$MXBeanImpl.dumpAllModuleInformation(ModuleLoader.java:725)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor13.invoke(Unknown Source
```

Comment: Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: How are you launching JConsole?

Comment: I have connected Jconsole in both ways. Firstly i have hosted the jboss in my local machine and launched Jconsole for local process, ended up with same issue. Secondly, i tried remote jmx was well but no luck. I'm facing this issue for dynamic modules. Is there way to search one module from one another module and scan all the jars and classes files inside ?

Comment: Are you launching `$JBOSS_HOME/bin/jconsole.sh`? What do you mean by "dynamic modules"?

Comment: Yes, i'm launching jconsole from Jboss Home. I mean application package (war) installed by us.I'm trying to get list of classes/jars loaded in all modules (including ServiceModule) installed in Jboss. I tried operation name 'dumpAllModuleInformation' for Local Module and Service Module
But i got successful result for Local Module only and Service Module thrown exception mentioned in the post.

Comment: @James R.Perkins Since JMX is throwing this exception, so i tried an alternative approach like hosting a servlet in Jboss to get the list of class loaded in JVM, but no luck. I'm able to get only list of classes present inside servlet module. My requirement is to list all the classes of ear/war files hosted in that server. As i know the module name already, i have passed the module name to Module Identifier class like mentioned below. 'code' ModuleIdentifier mi=ModuleIdentifier.fromString("deployment.test.war:main");Module module=Module.getModuleFromCallerModuleLoader(mi);